# I don't mean to be a [git], but shouldn't we encourage people to ask on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

There are currently 1824 [git](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/git) questions on Super User.

While they're on-topic here, there's 96,800 git questions on Stack Overflow, and having questions on different Stack Exchange sites means that you can't see linked or related questions under "Linked" or "Related", or mark questions as duplicate.

Should the tag for git recommend people to ask on Stack Overflow, even if they aren't using git for computer programming?

Comment: If they are within scope.  Why?  We want questions also.

Comment: I would expect questions with a broader scope to end up on SU. If you're interested in running gitea or gitlab-ce or similar products those questions would likely be more suitable for SU than for SO.